# Azure Data Factory - Add dynamic metadata in Copy Task

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-storage-account

I am currently using ADF to copy a bunch of files from FTP to Azure Storage account. I have to add
metadata for each file. I have been able to do this by adding metadata under the sink tab.

The problem is that this metadata is dynamic for each file and is derived from the name of the file. Can I do something like this in ADF or do I need a separate Azure Function / API to update metadata for each file?

Regards Tarun

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ADF expression here? [image]

Comment: Thanks but my requirement is that with the help of copy task, I need to move the files to azure blob storage and metadata for each file is derived from the filename. Is that possible in the expression?

Comment: you can use get metadata activity to get the file name first and pass it to your sink dataset as well as the metadata

Comment: I cant find any dynamic content for filename. Do u have any example?

Comment: @TarunBhatt, it would be something like @item().name

Comment: @RodionSychev - can't see anything like there. Do u have a snapshot

Comment: @TarunBhatt, well, in the 'Add dynamic content' window for the Metadata value you would have an option to pick the Current item of the ForEach iterator that is **@item()** and then just grab the item's name by appending '.name' so the result is going to be `@item().name`